# How do you get percentages from the Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I've followed the guide and managed to get, for example, a devices report.

```
  $analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery(
          $period,
          'ga:deviceCategory',
          [
              'max-results' => 10,
              'metrics' => 'ga:sessions, ga:avgSessionDuration',
              'dimensions' => 'ga:deviceCategory',
              'sort'=>'-ga:sessions'
          ]
      );
```

The results come as a number of sessions. Is there any way to get a percentage of sessions based on the total number of sessions elegantly, or do I have to query this first and then use the value and calculate it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Analytics API can only return the dimensions and metrics that it has available 
[Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

Any advanced continuations will need to be done by you after you have downloaded the data that there is available.